# How can I get a string without a SubString?

Tags: c#, string

I get word in text as:

```
string s="abbcdefbbgh"
string a = s.Substring(1, 2);
```

result is a="bb";

How do I get the inverse value: `a="acdefbbgh"`, that is the value without that substring?

Comment: Are you seeking `s.IndexOf("bb")`?

Comment: Do you want to get the string without the two letters?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you're looking for [`String.Remove`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8d7z2kk.aspx).

Answer (score 7):

There are several ways. For example, you can use the `Remove` method:

```
string a = s.Remove(1, 2);
```

You can use two `Substring` calls and concatenate the results:

```
string a = s.Substring(0, 1) + s.Substring(1 + 2);
```

You can use a `StringBuilder` object:

```
StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder(s);
b.Remove(1, 2);
string a = b.ToString();
```

You can use Linq extensions:

```
string a = new String(s.Where((c, i) => i < 1 || i > 2).ToArray());
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way,

```
string.Format("{0}{1}", s.Substring(0, 1), s.Substring(3));
```

---

[`string.Remove`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12260372/659190) is better.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
int start = 1;
int end = 2;

string a = s.Substring(0,start) + s.Substring(end+1);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for:

```
string a = s.Remove(1,2);
```

And with help of `SubString()`:

```
string a = s.Substring(0, 1) + s.Substring(3, s.Length);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 string s = "abbcdefbbgh";
 string a = s.Remove(1, 2);
```